# How can I download price information for multiple stocks at once?

Tags: curated-data, finance

I have a list of stock tickers. Is it possible to download price information over a period of time all in one go, or download other types of information across multiple stocks in one go?

Comment: I assume that you want to do it in one go to have simultaneous downloads (and thus speed up the download of several datasets simultaneously).  Unfortunately I do not know if this is possible using `FinancialData`/`WolframAlpha`, but if you download the data yourself from other sources, version 9 includes [asynchronous downloads functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AsynchronousTasks.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you have a list of tickers you can simply use `Map` to get stock data for each of them, like so:

```
listOfStocks = {"AAPL", "GOOG", "MS"};
stockData = FinancialData[#, "Jan. 1, 2005"] & /@ listOfStocks;
DateListPlot[stockData]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]